# "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable" while using scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Ran into a little bump just now while practicing web scraping, has anyone encountered this error before (below). I also the full BASH output there as well below the script.

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

"`TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`"

````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
import scrapy
from scrapy import Request
import json
from pprint import pprint

class JobsSpider1(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "dev"
    allowed_domains = ["loopnet.com"]
    start_urls = ['https://www.loopnet.com/search/commercial-real-estate/miami-fl/for-sale/']


    def parse(self, response):
        json_data = response.body.decode('utf-8')
        for datas in json_data:
            #pprint job_id = datas('Lower')

            pprint(datas('Lower'))

```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````



2019-12-27 13:24:59 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.8.0 started (bot: dev_me)
2019-12-27 13:24:59 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.4.2.0, libxml2 2.9.9, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.5.2, w3lib 1.21.0, Twisted 19.10.0, Python 3.6.9 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:44:02) -
 [GCC 8.3.0], pyOpenSSL 19.1.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019), cryptography 2.8, Platform Linux-5.0.0-37-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-18.04-bionic
2019-12-27 13:24:59 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': 'dev_me', 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'dev_me.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['dev_me.spiders'], 'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Wi
ndows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36'}
2019-12-27 13:24:59 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 5022c2520f20b678
￼
2019-12-27 13:24:59 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2019-12-27 13:24:59 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2019-12-27 13:24:59 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2019-12-27 13:24:59 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2019-12-27 13:24:59 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2019-12-27 13:24:59 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2019-12-27 13:24:59 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2019-12-27 13:24:59 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.loopnet.com/search/commercial-real-estate/miami-fl/for-sale/> (referer: None)
2019-12-27 13:25:00 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://www.loopnet.com/search/commercial-real-estate/miami-fl/for-sale/> (referer: None)
￼
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bbrown/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 654, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/home/bbrown/Documents/GitHub/main_stage/scrape_projects/scrapy_projects/dev_me/dev_me/spiders/ice_cream.py", line 17, in parse
    pprint(datas('Lower'))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
2019-12-27 13:25:00 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2019-12-27 13:25:00 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 337,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 59251,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 1.00937,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 27, 21, 25, 0, 125020),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 1,
 'log_count/ERROR': 1,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'memusage/max': 52645888,
 'memusage/startup': 52645888,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'spider_exceptions/TypeError': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 27, 21, 24, 59, 115650)}
2019-12-27 13:25:00 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Comment: Because `datas` is a `chr`.

Comment: To be clear, `datas` is a one character length `str`. Python doesn't have a `chr` type (or at least one relevant here).

Answer (score 1):

`json_data` is a string (in python, an `str` object), thus when iterating over it each `datas` you get will be a single character length `str`. Then when running        `pprint(datas('Lower'))`, python thinks you're attempting to call a function with the name `datas` and one parameter, the string literal `'Lower'`. As you can't call a `str`, only a function (more accurately, an object with the method `__call__` defined), the interpreter errors at this point.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I tried to update to a non-numerical JSON field but I am getting the same error```pprint(datas('SpaceSizeLabelForLand'))``` ? Any thoughts? How should I go about calling a string? Sorry, I am newer to python overall as well.

Comment: You *can't* call a string. You can only call a function. Whatever it is you're trying to do, that isn't the right syntax for it. It seems like you expect `datas` to be a dictionary. Could you explain your logic and what you're trying to do in greater depth?

Comment: Well I am trying to print a specific piece of text/value within the total response body. An example, if I wanted to print all areas that mention ```data-id``` @kopecs